# syntax issue with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I'm creating a list with jquery

```
$('<li value="0" onclick="'if(cond){ }'"> </li>).appendTo('#ul list');
```

The problem is in the section onclick, can someone tell me the right syntax?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? and `li` has not a value attribute.

Comment: Next time, check the browser's error console first. Your code throws.

Comment: Btw, LI elements don't have a `value` attribute, i.e. the HTML standard doesn't define such an attribute for LI elements.

Comment: problem solved thanks to @xdazz, and li do have value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use jQuery, then don't use the `onclick` attribute.

```
$('<li>').attr('value', '0').click(function() {
  if (cond) {
    //...
  }
}).appendTo('#ul list');
```

Comment: This would achieve what I suppose the user was asking. But the expression "#ul list" for the selector seems strange to me.

Comment: @emas You may be right, but that is what the OP is using. I am also not sure what what `list` references. I think he wants `$('#list')` and is confused about the `#` symbol. I think he wants the UL named LIST.

Comment: @user1638466 mark the answer as answered (hover over the number to its left and click the tick)!